# How to cast from hexadecimal to string in C?

Tags: c, casting

How to cast from hexadecimal to string in C?

Comment: Elaborate your question and you get elaborated answers

Comment: There is no "hexadecimal" type in C.

Comment: It is a real question, a beginner just got the terminology slightly wrong - can we be a bit more helpful please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot simply 'cast', you will need to use [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) to do the convertion:

```
unsigned int hex = 0xABC123FF;
char hexString[256];
sprintf(hexString, "0x%08X", hex);
```

If you want to 'cast' it to string in order to print it, you can use [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) directly:

```
unsigned int hex = 0xABC123FF;
printf("0x%08X", hex);
```

Comment: I thought `snprintf` is BSD only?

Comment: It's in the C99 standard library.

Comment: Oh wow, I did not know that. sadly, OP did not give platform/compiler, so I would like to keep it compatible with non-C99 compilers (read as: MSVC).

Comment: MSVC has a version called `_snprintf`.

Comment: I should mention that `_snprintf` does *not* nul-terminate the output string if the formatted string is longer than the buffer, so one should wrap `_snprintf` inside a `snprintf` function that calls `_snprintf` and then explicitly terminates the buffer (to make it behave the same as `snprintf` on other platforms).

Comment: Yay.. let's complicate the OP's request even more! Look, The OP is most definitely a beginner. Do you want to complicate his understanding by using `#ifdef`'s to re-define `_snprintf` and to handle the problem Greg suggested? I'm sorry, but I won't complicate this answer for a beginner.

Comment: Not to mention no 32bit or 64bit number has 256 hexadecimal digits.

Comment: My comments were not meant for the OP, but rather for people who might come across this page in the future and believe that `sprintf` or `_snprintf` is a good, safe idea.

Comment: `sprintf` is perfectly safe when used the way LiraNuna did.  An upper bound on the number of digits produced by `%x` can be determined from the range of the input number.

Comment: always use "08x" instead "8x"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast from a number to a string in C. You'll have to call a function for that purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Just stumbled over this old thread. Who says one cannot cast hex to string? That's a lie, I can:

```
unsigned int hex = 0xABC123FF;
char *str = (char*)&hex;
```

Okay it doesn't make sense printing it as C string (zero terminated), but I casted it ;)